# Multidimensional array to single array, with full key and separator

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this:

```
['firstTest' => ['secondTest' => 'x', 'thirdTest' => 'y'], 'fourthTest => 'z'];
```

I would like to create array like this:

```
['firstTest.secondTest' => 'x', 'firstTest.thirdTest' => 'y', 'fourthTest' => 'z']
```

I need to do it with PHP.

My array is also nested with 5-10 times.

Comment: Found the dupe with 2 seconds of Google search. You might have to make some small tweaks but the essence remains the same.

Comment: This solution may also work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: Thanks. I found it, but my array is more nested, so this solution doesn't work.

Comment: It works fine for the example you have given in the question. If you have a more complex situation - then show a proper example of that.